# за цену или по цене?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов, предлоги

Увидела слоган: "Все за низкие цены". Может быть, вернее будет: "Все по низким ценам"?
Объясните, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Слоган*** — лаконичная, **легко запоминающаяся** фраза, выражающая суть рекламного сообщения. А для этого  в нем должны быть **яркие** детали.

***По низким ценам*** (Д.п.) — это правильно, обыкновенно и скучно.

***За низкие цены*** (за что? В.п.)  — разговорный вариант с оттенком **метафоричности.** По аналогии: купить за небольшие деньги — купить за низкие цены. **Деньги как цены**.

**Сравнить** (купить за что?)

*Купить  задорого, задешево*. Русский орфографический словарь.

*За что купил, за то и продаю* ( погов.) — только повторяю то, что слышал, не ручаюсь за достоверность.